# Amazon Route 53 Latency Based Routing - How to check were a request went

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've setup a couple of EC2 instances in different regions and have configured A record sets in my hosted zone. All is working correctly, but I want to be able to check were a certain request is going. So if a request is done through webpagetest.org from Europe, is there a way I can check that Route 53 is routing it correctly to my EC2 instance in Ireland (assuming that it has the lowest latency)?

Answer (score 0):

That site doesnt tell you what ip address is resolved in the request. You should try something like pingdom to see if the request is resolving to the correct ip address from different points around the world.

Comment: I'm currently using Webpagetest.org API in combination with a self made tool to test. Yesterday I tested Sydney with a wrong Route 53 setup and saw nothing coming into the monitor of AWS. After fixing that I saw a significant drop in my average document complete time (over 10 requests). And saw traffic in the AWS monitor, so I know it is working.

I looked at pingdom for a second, and tested my site. Couldn't see were traffic was heading though. Should I use a different tool for that?

Comment: I thought you could get the resolved IP address of the request, but it appears that is only available if the request fails via root cause analysis. If you can set up the check that it will fail, you can see which ip address its resolving to.